# Paypal : (#11452: Merchant not enabled for reference transactions)

Tags: paypal, billing-agreements

Magento 2 :

I am not sure if it's only technical issue but since Paypal think it is..

While tring to integrate a billing agreement on customer account (frontend), I have this message with paypal :

> Merchant not enabled for reference transactions (#11452: Merchant not
>   enabled for reference transactions).

I have no idea at all, or where looking at. Any idea ?